How to read value from any type in Golang
How can I read an object from an any[]? The below code fails when it traverse the any array.
Please take a look at the code snippet -
type Location struct {
    Name string
    Home string
}

type MyRow struct {
    Type int
    DataRow any 
}

type MyTransaction struct {
    TID    int
    Rows   []MyRow
}

type SoftTran map[int]MyTransaction
var MapTran SoftTran

func main() {
    MapTran = make(SoftTran)
    
    var TT1 MyTransaction 

    var row1 MyRow
    row1.Type = 100
    row1.DataRow = &Location {"YourHome", "GoHome"};
    TT1.Rows = append(TT1.Rows, row1)
    //read 
    
    for _, row := range TT1.Rows {
        switch row.Type {
            case 100:
                val := row.DataRow.(Location)
                fmt.Printf("%s %s", val.Home, val.Name)
            default:
        }
    }
}

The above code fails when it executes the following line -
val := row.DataRow.(Location)
fmt.Printf("%s %s", val.Home, val.Name)

Thank you for your help in solving the above problem.

You store a pointer to a location (&Location{...} which has type *Location) in DataRow and then type-assert it back out as a Location with row.DataRow.(Location). This fails, because a pointer to a Location is not a Location.
The error message you get literally tells you this:
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *main.Location, not main.Location
Instead, you should use row.DataRow.(*Location).
